# Removal Background with Shadows on HUE

Tags: image-processing, image, computer-vision

I have an image of a leaf on a poorly white screen and need to find out just the leaf:

[image: Leaf Image]

The problem is that it contains greenish shadows, so simple color-based methods are not enough. Thus, I need some preprocessing to achieve an uniform background and to enhance important features. The goal is to delete undesired noise
and distortions to apply an Expectation Maximization algorithm.

[image: HSV Image Channels]

I tried playing with OpenCV fastNlMeansDenoising, but it is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ChanVeseBinarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChanVeseBinarize.html) seems to do exactly what you're looking for:

```
Row[{img, ChanVeseBinarize[img], 
   HighlightImage[img, ChanVeseBinarize[img]]}]
```

[image]